# bootstrap column grids are appearing in one single columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have created a simple page in bootstrap 4 . I want to three show packages in same row .I have placed my contents properly and make sure all div's are properly closed.Still the columns are coming one below. I want them in same row. Here is Plunker Link. Thanks. [plnkr_preview][1]

```
[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/RxM568gMJI1kFAYkv8Br?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seems to don't understand bootstrap grid properly. If you edit line 30 to be

```
<div class="row"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
```

changing `col-md-12` to `row` will fix your issue.

Note:

You should wrap `col-md-*` which add up to 12 or not inside a `row` . Its not a good practise of wrapping `col-md-*` inside another `col-md-*` directly without a `row`. You should always wrap inside a `row` first before further splitting the layout into another columns.

Comment: @amarghodke https://plnkr.co/edit/Lc7zJZwjWnYR42E5iYOD?p=preview looks working to me into 3 column side by side

Comment: yes. it is working, can you guide me for the note you have given ?